# How to Integrate RESTful service in the WSO2 ESB

Tags: api, wso2, integration, esb, wso2-esb

I am trying to create an integration layer through the WSO2 ESB (RESTful API Service Integration).

Endpoint - http://www.thomas-bayer.com/

Context - /sqlrest

and

URI-template - /CUSTOMER/3

( API Endpoint - www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3 )

After everything when I'm trying to invoke the api request with ( http://localhost:8280:/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3 )

I'm getting the response as full HTML with 404 error code rather than the XML Data.

Comment: Sorry I'm not great with the URLs but why local host and ?port number? Instead of endpoint?

Comment: @marshalcraft localhost is deployed by the ESO2 ESB in your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this API in WSO2 ESB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
     name="sqlrestAPI"
     context="/sqlrest">
   <resource methods="GET" protocol="http" uri-template="/CUSTOMER/{id}">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="GET"
                     uri-template="http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/{uri.var.id}"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

And call it with (OFFSET = 3 in my case):

```
curl -v http://localhost:8283/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3
```

The response:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8283 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8283 (#0)
> GET /sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.25.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.25.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8u zlib/1.2.6 libssh2/1.4.0
> Host: localhost:8283
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2017 16:40:08 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
<?xml version="1.0"?><CUSTOMER xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <ID>3</ID>
    <FIRSTNAME>Michael</FIRSTNAME>
    <LASTNAME>Clancy</LASTNAME>
    <STREET>542 Upland Pl.</STREET>
    <CITY>San Francisco</CITY>
</CUSTOMER>* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: I've figured it out myself. But you are right this is the right solution. Thanks...

Comment: glad to hear that you can find the solution by your self. can you mark my anwser as the right one?

Answer (score 0):

The context you provide does not need to be anything from the actual endpoint URL.

For example, you can define context as `myapi`. Then you have 2 options.

**Option 1:**

Configure endpoint as `http://www.thomas-bayer.com/`

Then you can call your API as `http://localhost:8280/myapi/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3`

**Option 2:**

Configure endpoint as `http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/`

Then you can call your API as `http://localhost:8280/myapi/CUSTOMER/3`